# Why tabs are not the same in Android?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I am testing with `ViewPager` and `ActionBar.Tab` and the problem is in the following image.

[image]

I was expecting the tabs to view on every device as same. They are same on Note 3 and S4 but not on Xperia L.

Question is:

- Are they same because of Android 4.4 ??
- Are they same because of xxhdpi ??
- How can I make them look alike on every (or most) device possible ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the default theme configuration. Please check in the androidmanifest.xml file of your application.

If it contains the style as

```
android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault
```

Reason:

Every OEMs have their own varient of  theme.

Solution:

Be specific about the theme needs to be applied like below

> @android:style/Theme.Holo

Comment: In my Manifest.xml, there is no android:style. Could you please tell me where in xml should I put this line ?

Comment: you much check the style under /vaues/styles.xml. Please post here the contents of  /values/styles.xml & /values-14/styles.xml

Comment: note that in your androidmanifest.xml will have an entry android:theme="<theme specification>", please post here that too

Comment: there is no android:theme="". Should I write it like this
<manifest android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo"> ??

Comment: it didn't work btw. I have no theme named Holo. Are there any predefined themes ??

Comment: by default, device default theme is select. so, consider adding android:theme in <application> tag in your android manifest file.  Also, you should have a clear understand on how theme works. Please go thru the link here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html